# Lost Textfield Input Values After Switching Back From Another Controller Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a master view and some detail views, on one of my detail views, I have a couple of textfields, after typed in the textfields, from the master view I switched to a different controller, and when I switch back, the values I put into these text fields are all cleared. How do I keep the typed values?

Comment: You should give minimal working example code. My feeling is you'll need to store the text from the field and restore it once you return to your view.

Comment: If you're pushing a new view controller, the values should stay in the textfields when you pop back. If you're popping from the view controller with the textfields, the view controller is destroyed and so obviously the text won't be there.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my issue. I used segue on the storyboard.

Comment: save them using nsuserdefaults!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. I use Core Data, first I store the textfield values into NSManagedObjectContext at my viewController, inside textFieldDidEndEditing, I assign all the textfield values to NSManagedObjectContext. It worked.